# Uploading image files to a different server in Spring 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

Folks, I have a question which may sound like it has been addressed before but its not!!

I am trying to upload images from my D drive to a server using Spring MVC 3.
But when i try to copy a file from Drive D to Drive C it works!!
Eg:- Load an image from my `http://localhost:8080/loadImage` and browse for an image to load into http://q.someimagerepository.com/
Code:-

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
OutputStream outputStream = null;
inputStream = helloFile.getInputStream();
outputStream = new FileOutputStream("http://q.someimagerepository.com/newImage");
int readBytes = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
while ((readBytes = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 10000)) != -1) {
outputStream.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
}
outputStream.close();
inputStream.close();
```

Where helloFIle(CommonsMultipartFile file) is a file I am loading from the screen after I browse and select it.
Do we have to send the file extension as well?

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am getting an error like :-

**(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)**

Please let me know the correct way of doing this.
Also when I try copy a file from Drive D to Drive C, the following code works but not in the aforementioned scenario :-

```
//Correct approach in SPRING
helloFile.transferTo(new File("C:/"));
```

Comment: Do you want to upload image using `new FileOutputStream("http://q.someimagerepository.com/newImage");`?

Comment: Hi ProblemFactory, that is the server path right. I mean if I change it to C:/, it works fine. That is correct way right? Or is there any other way? Please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe we have to include the JAR file for the type of server.
Make use of the jar file - Open a http connection - Add the data(image in this case) to the input stream - Write the data using Output stream.

Connection.put(imageurl,.....)

Took a while but we got it. Thank you Stackoverflow team for the response.

Regards,
LE

Answer (score 0):

Moving an image of "C:" to "D:" or www.webpage.com/app to drive "C:" on Server?

Regards.

Comment: Moving to www.webpage.com/app on the server.

Comment: If you want to upload a file to the server, in a folder of the same project you could use this example http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-file-upload-example/